# Get value of property with reflection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

i need to get value of property in C# with reflection .

i need to find lenght of string and compare to max .

i write this code :

```
public static bool ValidateWithReflection(T model)
    {
        bool validate = false;
        var cls = typeof(T);
        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = cls.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo item in propertyInfos)
        {
            var max = item.GetCustomAttributes<MaxLenghtName>().Select(x => x.Max).FirstOrDefault();
            if (max != 0)
            {
                var lenght = item.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(cls, null);
                if ((int)lenght > max)
                {
                    return validate = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return validate;
    }
```

and this for get value of property :

`var lenght = item.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(cls, null);`

but it show me this error :

> ```
>   Message "Object does not match target type."    string
> ```

now whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: The fact that you're not using `model` anywhere should be a hint.

Comment: Use `model` instead of `cls` since `GetValue` parameter asks for the object to get the value from. `var lenght = item.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(model, null);`

Comment: `cls` is just the type, it doesn't have any values so you can't `getValue` from it. You need to getValue on an actual instance of that type, not the type itself. Secondly, why are you using the indexed override for `GetValue` and supplying it with null? Just call `GetValue(obj)`

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard still show me that error

Comment: `.GetValue(cls, null);` is correct only if property is `static`; `GetValue(cls, model);` instead

Comment: `MaxLenghtName` You may wish to fix that typo. :)

Comment: Try `var length = item.GetValue(model)` Item is already the property you are trying to get, you dont need to chain back to it. Your code basically says "given this type, get this property, then get the type its from, then get the property again, then get the value of the property from the type", it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by `validate = true;`? Did you mean `==`? Why do you want a method called `Validate` to return `true` if the data is **longer** than the max length?

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard thank you

Comment: Validating by reflection means a class object already has the data - by many metrics, its too late for validation by that point!  Why not add code to the prop setter for it to react to bad/too short data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `item.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name)` supposed to do? `item` is a `PropertyInfo` instance. You're not looking to get properties of that, but of your `model`.

So simplify your code to this:

```
var value = item.GetValue(model) as string;
if (value?.Length > max)
{
    return validate = true;
}
```